# Apscheduler Python: Cron not running on interval every time

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am using apscheduler to run the cron jobs, and this is the query

```
scheduler.add_job(triggerTask,'interval', hours=1)
```

This cron job should run every hour but it does not. Please let me know the reason and how I can fix it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What does your whole program look like? Does it finish directly after this line or does it continue running for an hour?

Comment: Which kind of scheduler do you use?